# Use of properties.InvalidateListItem()

Tags: event-receivers

I am not getting relevant resources which would explain the use of `properties.InvalidateListItem()`. Even MSDN has no definition for it.

Can someone throw light on it

Answer (score 0):

[Invalidates the current ListItem object.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.invalidatelistitem(v=office.14).aspx)This method is used to invalidate an outdated SPListItem object. The invalidation of an SPListItem object triggers the retrieval of the updated object after the next request is made.

[A sample method is provided below](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed3437e2-be0b-40e3-9ba8-c7ed4e32fa0b/question-about-propertiesinvalidatelistitem?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
      base.ItemAdding(properties);
      if (!(properties.UserLoginName == "SHAREPOINT\\system"))
      {
        try
        {
          throw new InvalidCreatorIdException("Please contact support to add a known URL to your list of release web sites.");
        }
        catch (InvalidCreatorIdException ex)
        {
          properties.Cancel = true;
          properties.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
          properties.InvalidateListItem();
          throw;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: So what does invalidate an outdated `SPListItem` means?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56607/instantiating-splistitems-in-event-receivers-best-practices

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee724407%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE can you elaborate on the consequences of not calling this method?